# What's the math behind CSS's background-size:cover

Tags: css, gd

I'm creating an "image generator" where users can upload an image and add text and/or draw on it. The outputted image is a fixed size (698x450).

On the client side, when the user uploads their image it is set as the background of a div that's 698x450 with background-size:cover. This makes it fill the area nicely.

The final combined image is generated by PHP using GD functions. My question is, how can I get the image to scale in PHP the same way it does in CSS. I want the result of the PHP script to look the same as if the image was set in CSS as it was above.
Does anyone know how browsers using background-size:cover calculate how to scale the image appropriately? I want to translate this into PHP.

Thanks

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Here's a logic behind cover calculations.

You have four base values :

```
imgWidth // your original img width
imgHeight

containerWidth // your container  width (here 698px)
containerHeight
```

Two ratios derived from these values :

```
imgRatio = (imgHeight / imgWidth)       // original img ratio
containerRatio = (containerHeight / containerWidth)     // container ratio
```

You want to find two new values :

```
finalWidth // the scaled img width
finalHeight
```

So :

```
if (containerRatio > imgRatio) 
{
    finalHeight = containerHeight
    finalWidth = (containerHeight / imgRatio)
} 
else 
{
    finalWidth = containerWidth 
    finalHeight = (containerWidth / imgRatio)
}
```

... and you have the equivalent of a background-size : cover.

Comment: Not sure why but I had to change last line as `finalHeight = (containerWidth * imgRatio)` to work properly for my code

Comment: @Ergec, exactly! `imgRatio` is `height / width`. We need to multiply `height / width` by `width` to get `height`. @mddw, fix your answer, plaease

Comment: Is this the official implementation or reverse engineering?

Comment: The math of this did not work for me. The answer by Antriver did.

Answer (score 16):

I know this is a very old question, but the answer I wrote is actually cleaner by using max and mins on the ratios between the images instead of each image with itself:

```
var originalRatios = {
  width: containerWidth / imageNaturalWidth,
  height: containerHeight / imageNaturalHeight
};

// formula for cover:
var coverRatio = Math.max(originalRatios.width, originalRatios.height); 

// result:
var newImageWidth = imageNaturalWidth * coverRatio;
var newImageHeight = imageNaturalHeight * coverRatio;
```

I like this approach because it is very *systematic* — maybe it's the wrong word —. What I mean is you can get rid of the `if` statements and make it work in a more "math formula" kind of way (input = output, if that makes sense):

```
var ratios = {
  cover: function(wRatio, hRatio) {
    return Math.max(wRatio, hRatio);
  },

  contain: function(wRatio, hRatio) {
    return Math.min(wRatio, hRatio);
  },

  // original size
  "auto": function() {
    return 1;
  },

  // stretch
  "100% 100%": function(wRatio, hRatio) {
    return { width:wRatio, height:hRatio };
  }
};

function getImageSize(options) {
  if(!ratios[options.size]) {
    throw new Error(options.size + " not found in ratios");
  }

  var r = ratios[options.size](
    options.container.width / options.image.width,
    options.container.height / options.image.height
  );

  return {
    width: options.image.width * (r.width || r),
    height: options.image.height * (r.height || r)
  };
}
```

#### Usage

```js
const { width, height } = getImageSize({
  container: {width: 100, height: 100},
  image: {width: 200, height: 50},
  size: 'cover' // 'contain' | 'auto' | '100% 100%'
});
```

#### Playground

I created a `jsbin` [here](https://jsbin.com/vecuho/3/edit?js,console) if you want to take a look at what I mean with *systematic* (it also has a `scale` method that I thought was not needed in this answer but very useful for something other than the usual).

Comment: I think the word you were looking for is "semantic" maybe?

Comment: Could be. Now that I read it again, maybe the correct word is "mathematization", or just "simplified"/"streamlined"? In mathematics, 'systematic' usually refers to a *process* that follows a specific & organized pattern/plan/system, but this code isn't a process, per se. IMO, it is just a simplification to remove the if statements and transform it into more of a "formula" approach.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to mdi for pointing me in the right direction, but that didn't seem quite right.
This is the solution that worked for me:

```
    $imgRatio = $imageHeight / $imageWidth;
    $canvasRatio = $canvasHeight / $canvasWidth;

    if ($canvasRatio > $imgRatio) {
        $finalHeight = $canvasHeight;
        $scale = $finalHeight / $imageHeight;
        $finalWidth = round($imageWidth * $scale , 0);
    } else {
        $finalWidth = $canvasWidth;
        $scale = $finalWidth / $imageWidth;
        $finalHeight = round($imageHeight * $scale , 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled across this QA after a long search for a way how to scale and position a background image on a div to match an html background image while also supporting browser resizing and ad-hoc positioning of the div and I came up with this.

[image: background image of a div positioned to match html background]

```css
:root {
  /* background image size (source) */

  --bgw: 1920;
  --bgh: 1080;

  /* projected background image size and position */

  --bgscale: max(calc(100vh / var(--bgh)), calc(100vw / var(--bgw)));

  --pbgw: calc(var(--bgw) * var(--bgscale)); /* projected width */
  --pbgh: calc(var(--bgh) * var(--bgscale)); /* projected height */

  --bgLeftOverflow: calc((var(--pbgw) - 100vw) / 2); 
  --bgTopOverflow: calc((var(--pbgh) - 100vh) / 2);
}
```

JS equivalent

```js
window.onresize = () => {
  const vw100 = window.innerWidth
  const vh100 = window.innerHeight

  /* background image size (source) */

  const bgw = 1920
  const bgh = 1080

  /* projected background image size and position */

  const bgscale = Math.max(vh100 / bgh, vw100 / bgw)

  const projectedWidth  = bgw * bgscale | 0
  const projectedHeight = bgh * bgscale | 0

  const leftOverflow = (projectedWidth  - vw100) / 2 | 0
  const topOverflow  = (projectedHeight - vh100) / 2 | 0

  console.log(bgscale.toFixed(2), projectedWidth, projectedHeight, leftOverflow, topOverflow)
}
```

Try resizing a window with this snippet to see the result.
Best viewed in *Full page* view. tip: Open console.

```js
window.onresize = () => {
  const vw100 = window.innerWidth
  const vh100 = window.innerHeight
  const bgw = 1920
  const bgh = 1080

  const bgscale = Math.max(vh100 / bgh, vw100 / bgw)

  const projectedWidth = bgw * bgscale | 0
  const projectedHeight = bgh * bgscale | 0

  const leftOverflow = (projectedWidth - vw100) / 2 | 0
  const topOverflow = (projectedHeight - vh100) / 2 | 0

  console.log(bgscale.toFixed(2), projectedWidth, projectedHeight, leftOverflow, topOverflow)
}
```

```css
:root {
  /* background image size */
  --bgurl: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iy4y.jpg');
  --bgw: 1000;
  --bgh: 600;
  
  --bgscale: max(calc(100vh / var(--bgh)), calc(100vw / var(--bgw)));
  
  --pbgw: calc(var(--bgw) * var(--bgscale));
  --pbgh: calc(var(--bgh) * var(--bgscale));
  
  --bgLeftOverflow: calc((var(--pbgw) - 100vw) / 2);
  --bgTopOverflow: calc((var(--pbgh) - 100vh) / 2);
}

html {
  background: #000 var(--bgurl) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#panel {
  --x: 100px;
  --y: 100px;
  --w: 200px;
  --h: 150px;
  
  position: absolute;
  left: var( --x);
  top: var( --y);
  width: var(--w);
  height: var(--h);
  
  background-image: var(--bgurl);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: calc(0px - var(--bgLeftOverflow) - var(--x)) calc(0px - var(--bgTopOverflow) - var(--y));
  background-size: calc(var( --bgscale) * var(--bgw));
  filter: invert(1);
}
```

```html
<div id="panel"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

When using `background-size: cover`, it is scaled to the smallest size that covers the entire background.

So, where it is thinner than it is tall, scale it until its width is the same as the area. Where it is taller than it is thin, scale it until its height is the same as the area.

When it is larger than the area to cover, scale it down until it fits (if there is less overflow in height, scale until the same height, if there is less overflow in width, scale until the same width).

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are missing a step.

Step 1. Scale the image depending on the aspect ratio of the canvass or the image. The smallest size that covers the entire canvas. Thanks to anrtiver

Step 2. Crop the image, otherwise it wont be central.

```
 function ImageCover($img1, $canvass_width, $canvass_height) {
    
      $img1_width = imagesx($img1);
      $img1_height = imagesy($img1);
      $img1_ratio = $img1_height / $img1_width;
      
      $canvass_ratio = $canvass_width / $canvass_height;
    
    //scale 
      if ($canvass_ratio < $img1_ratio) {
        $finalHeight = $canvass_height;
        $scale = $finalHeight / $img1_height;
        $finalWidth = $img1_width * $scale;
      } else {
        $finalWidth = $canvass_width;
        $scale = $finalWidth / $img1_width;
        $finalHeight = $img1_height * $scale;
      }
      
      $img1_scalled = imagescale($img1, $finalWidth, $finalHeight);
    
      $img1_scalled_width = imagesx($img1_scalled);
      $img1_scalled_height = imagesy($img1_scalled);
    
      $img1 = $img1_scalled;
      $img1_width = $img1_scalled_width;
      $img1_height = $img1_scalled_height;
    
    
    //crop
      $x = 0;
      $y = 0;
      if($img1_scalled_width > $canvass_width) {
        $difference_x = $img1_scalled_width - $canvass_width;
        $x = $difference_x / 2;
      } else {
        $difference_y = $img1_scalled_height - $canvass_height;   
        $y = ($difference_y / 2);
      }
    
    
    
      $img1 = imagecrop($img1, ['x' => $x, 'y' => $y, 'width' => $canvass_width, 'height' => $canvass_height]);
      
      return $img1;
    
    
    } //ImageCover
```