# jQuery width and height return the old values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on placing image in the exact middle of the object, to make it look like `background-size: cover;`. To do it, I've set the width or the height (the smaller among them) to `100%` and the other one to `auto`. Then I've set the top and the right to `50%`. At the end, I tried to set the margins (the right and the top) to minus half of the height and the width.

Here is my code:

```
$.fn.extend({
    middleify: function(){
        var i = $(this);
        var f = i.parent();
        var wh = i.height() == i.width() ? f.width() < f.height() : i.width() > i.height();
        var hw = i.height() == i.width() ? f.height() < f.width() : i.height() > i.width();
        return i.css({position: "relative", "z-index": 2, width: hw ? "100%" : "auto", height: wh ? "100%" : "auto", top: "50%", right: "50%", "margin-right": 0 - (i.width()) / 2, "margin-top": 0 - (i.width() / 2)});
    }
});
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/beb8o2g6/2/**

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what your end goal here is.

Comment: @Jack I want the image to be in the middle of the rectangle, exactly like `background-size: cover;`

Comment: @Jack I've added the goal: http://jsfiddle.net/beb8o2g6/2/

Comment: Why do you need to do this with javascript? Knowing why you can't just use background-size might help to come up with a different solution.

Comment: Those images are important part of the website, and I've read somewhere that Googlebot can see only the images in the `img` object, not in the background image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are too many things you missed checking.

**First**

Your `$(this);` contains an array of elements because your selector is `img`

```
$("img").middleify();
```

Yet you are storing values like this :

```
    var i = $(this);
    var f = i.parent();
```

**Second**

```
var wh = i.height() == i.width() ? f.width() < f.height() : i.width() > i.height();
var hw = i.height() == i.width() ? f.height() < f.width() : i.height() > i.width();
```

You don't need to have this kind of conditions, it really does confuse me. How about just setting the `width:100%` then `height: auto` since your container has bigger `width` than it's height.

**Third**

```
return i.css({position: "relative", "z-index": 2, width: hw ? "100%" : "auto", height: wh ? "100%" : "auto", top: "50%", right: "50%", "margin-right": 0 - (i.width()) / 2, "margin-top": 0 - (i.width() / 2)});
```

You are computing the `width` and `height` of the element which you haven't set those values yet. It's more likely it will get the default values.

To fix that you have to set the `width` and `height` first and separately to the computation

`"margin-right": 0 - (i.width()) / 2, "margin-top": 0 - (i.width() / 2)});`

**Putting them together**

```
$.fn.extend({
  middleify: function(){
    var i = $(this);
    $.each(i, function(index, value) {
       var elm = $(value);
       var f = elm.parent();  
       elm.css({position: "relative", "z-index": 2, width: "100%", height:"auto", top: "50%", left: "50%"});

       elm.css({"margin-left": 0 - (elm.width()) / 2, "margin-top": 0 - (elm.height() / 2)}); 
    });
  }
});
$("img").middleify();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d4cb8kbm/22/)

**Update**

Since setting a wider image `width` `100%` will cause a problem, let's make use of this logic on [`background:cover`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10285134/whats-the-math-behind-csss-background-sizecover)

```
$.fn.extend({
  middleify: function(){
    var i = $(this);
    $.each(i, function(index, value) {
       var elm = $(value);
       var f = elm.parent();  

        var imgWidth = elm.width();
        var imgHeight = elm.height();

        var containerWidth = f.width();
        var containerHeight = f.height();

        var imgRatio = (imgHeight / imgWidth);
        var containerRatio = (containerHeight / containerWidth);

        if (containerRatio > imgRatio) {
          var finalHeight = containerHeight;
          var finalWidth = (containerHeight / imgRatio);
        } 
        else {
          var finalWidth = containerWidth;
          var finalHeight = (containerWidth * imgRatio);
        }

       elm.css({position: "relative", "z-index": 2, width: finalWidth, height: finalHeight, top: "50%", left: "50%"});

       elm.css({"margin-left": 0 - (elm.width()) / 2, "margin-top": 0 - (elm.height() / 2)}); 
    });
  }
});
$("img").middleify();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d4cb8kbm/26/)

Comment: There is a problem with setting width to 100%. Some of the images I'm working with looks like this one: https://scontent-fra.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xfp1/t31.0-8/1502690_477245699047085_1960157551_o.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with just CSS...

```css
figure {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

figure img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
    <h1>The attempt</h1>
    <figure>
        <img src="https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/t31.0-8/1601993_484655221639466_890925492_o.jpg" />
    </figure>
    
    <figure>
        <img src="https://scontent-fra.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash2/v/t1.0-9/580303_450139941757661_1330443402_n.jpg?oh=9ae59fa1b0e51a356b2ca50b0c160354&oe=55DDE28F" />
    </figure>
    
    <figure>
        <img src="https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xap1/v/t1.0-9/1618538_487714631333525_1011288966_n.jpg?oh=2e48acfd68c08d2ea27fa3e7ba8e9462&oe=55B2A1C5&__gda__=1441110764_e04ce223b16035ae8c496e00f8845212" />
    </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: I cannot set the width to 100%, because if the height is smaller then the width it won't fill the whole `figure`. Also, correct me if I'm wrong, but not all the browsers support `translate`.

Comment: `transform/translate` has the same browser support as `figure` so if you want to use `figure` you should be fine. http://caniuse.com/#search=transform

Comment: If so, then great! Thanks!